# Split complex string into mutliple parts using regex

Tags: regex, split

I've tried a lot to split this string into something i can work with, however my experience isn't enough to reach the goal. Tried first 3 pages on google, which helped but still didn't give me an idea how to properly do this:

I have a string which looks like this:

```
My Dogs,213,220#Gallery,635,210#Screenshot,219,530#Good Morning,412,408#
```

The result should be:

```
MyDogs
213,229
Gallery
635,210
Screenshot
219,530
Good Morning
412,408
```

Anyone have an idea how to use regex to split the string like shown above?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I'm using AutoIt.
But now that you mention it.. should have posted this in AutoIt related i think :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the shared patterns, it seems you're looking for a regex like the following:

```
[A-Za-z ]+|\d+,\d+
```

It matches two patterns:

- `[A-Za-z ]+`: any combination of letters and spaces
- `\d+,\d+`: any combination of digits + a comma + any combination of digits

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dLqO2g/1).

---

If you want a more strict regex, you can include the previous pattern between a lookbehind and a lookahead, so that you're sure that every match is preceeded by either a comma, a `#` or a start/end of string character.

```
(?<=^|,|#)([A-Za-z ]+|\d+,\d+)(?=,|#|$)
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2r4DDc/1).